# Is there an equivalent to subscribe for errors?

Tags: bacon.js

If a function yields an error immediately, like in the case below, onError will never be called because the error has already been sent by the time the **onError** attaches. If this was a value as opposed to an error, one could have used the **subscribe** method instead of **onValue**, but what recourse does one have if it's an error?

```
var legacyNodeFunction = function(callback) {
  callback(new Error('I fail IMMEDIATELY, not async!'), null)
}

function doThingsWithLegacyFunction() {
   return Bacon.fromNodeCallback(legacyNodeFunction)
}

var stream = doThingsWithLegacyFunction();
stream.onError(function(err) {
  console.log("this text will never be printed")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact the `subscribe` function gives you both values and errors.

It might be also that a Promise would suit your particular need better.

Or you can use .delay(0) to force it async so that both your handlers are called.

Comment: Will .delay(0) really work in this case, since delay doesn't affect initial values? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how to use it.